# align both axis to same scale/zero point

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a macro to create some charts, my orange line is on the primary axis with the blue and purple are on the secondary. I need the secondary zero point to start at the same as the primary, is there a change to my VBA code that would do this or align both axis to same scale?

[image]

```
Worksheets("Chart2").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = FileName
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=ChartData!$A$3:$A$" & FinalRowChart
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=ChartData!$B$3:$B$" & FinalRowChart




With ActiveChart
With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.XValues = "=ChartData!$P$5:$P$" & FinalRowBL
.Values = "=ChartData!$R$5:$R$" & FinalRowBL
.Name = "BD"
.AxisGroup = 2
End With
End With

With ActiveChart
With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.XValues = "=ChartData!$A$3:$A$" & FinalRowChart
.Values = "=ChartData!$G$3:$G$" & FinalRowChart
.Name = "Trace Line"
.AxisGroup = 2
End With
End With
```

Note: i cant set the min max of the secondary scale manually as different charts are ran off the scale of the primary will change significantly so it has to be done based on that.

Answer (score 1):

This will change the secondary axis to match the primary - also hopefully showing a way to do it without having to activate charts.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart2")
        
    cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale
    cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale

End Sub
```